# Return if string has valid characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to make function, that works like Windows' rename function [image].

When you type text and regex is `a-zA-Z0-9` then you can type only "alphanumeric" characters. But characters like -, _ or + would be accepted too. Also non-english characters like `č š ý ž í á` should be accepted too.

Comment: you can use [^\/:*?"<>|], check this http://www.regexr.com/ > CheatSheet, very useful

Comment: if I understand right, this regex will take all characters except of these in `[...]`?

Comment: except those in `[^]`

Comment: Yeas, thanks, XGreen did similar regex in his answer, now its good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to not allow those characters in the bubble then:

```
function filenameOk(name){
    return !/[\\/:*?<>|]/.test(name);
}

// filenameOk('čšýžíá') --> true
```

Comment: Actualy, this is regex from comment under my question, so I was right about bubbling them. Thanks, that is usefull, I will also add some my "exceptions" so it will be like I want.